# Approximation of integral in small neighborhood

Tags: integration, approximation

I'm having trouble verifying

$$
\int_x^{x+\delta_x} \int_y^{y+\delta_y} f(u,v)\ dv \ dv \approx f(x,y)\delta_x \delta_y \ ,
$$

for small $\delta_x$ and $\delta_y$.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. My first guess would be to use a 2 dimensional Taylor expansion in a way, but it seems that this approximation is made by an intuitive argument.

I find it reasonable to pick the value of $f$ at $(x,y)$, but how would one show the multiplication by $\delta_x \delta_y$

How would one derive this approximation being given that $\delta_x$ and $\delta_y$ are small?

**Context.**

I've come across this in studying continuous random variables, where $f(x,y)$ is the *joint denisity function*.

Comment: You are integrating over a region of area $\delta_x\delta_y$ a function which is approximately $f(x,y)$ there.

Comment: is the analogous in 1-variable:  $$\int_t^{t+\Delta t} f(w)dw=f(t)\Delta t?$$

Comment: Don't we need we need that the variables are separable $f(x,y) = g(x)h(y)$  to use that?

Comment: Suppose $f(u, v) = C$ where C is some constant. Can you see that the approximation holds (actually, it is exact - not an approximation, even when the region is not small)? Then if the region *is* small, the function is *approximately* constant in the region.

Comment: @Nick Yes, I see that the function is approximately constant in the region. I'm having trouble seeing the link with the 1 dimensional case where we can just indeed multiply by the small deviation. What motivates the same use in the 2 dimensional case; multiplying by $\delta_x \delta_y$, that is.

Comment: The double integral $\int_x^{x+\delta_x} \int_y^{y+\delta_y} \ du \ dv = \delta_x \delta_y$ is the area of the little rectangle, since you can factor out the constant and the resulting integral is then the product of two one-dimensional integrals.

Comment: @Nick Terrific! :) That makes sense.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I should have taken note of your comment, at first; I wasn't paying attention. :)

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continuous at $r=(x,y)$ then for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a ball $B_r(\epsilon)$ so that for all $x\in B_r(\epsilon)$

$$
|f(x)-f(r)| < \epsilon
$$

Now select $\delta_x,\delta_y$ so that $[x,x+\delta_x]\times[y,y+\delta_y]$ fit in that ball and you get
$$
\int_x^{x+\delta_x}\int_y^{y+\delta_y} (f(u,v) - f(x,y) + f(x,y)) \,dudv = A + f(x,y)\delta_x\delta_y,
$$ with
$$
A = \int_x^{x+\delta_x}\int_y^{y+\delta_y} f(u,v) - f(x,y) \, du dv.
$$ Hence we can estimate $|A|$ by
$$
|A| \leq \int_x^{x+\delta_x}\int_y^{y+\delta_y} |f(u,v) - f(x,y)| \, du dv \leq \epsilon \delta_x \delta_y.
$$
Hence the error can be made arbritrary small. You may want more control on the error on this equation if we assume all partial derivatives are uniformly bounded by C first differential then we can use with $e$ a unit vector of the correct direction and use $|(u,v)-(x,y)|=\delta$
$$
f(u,v) = f(x,y) + \int_0^\delta e \cdot \nabla f(r+et)\,dt
$$

and

$$
|f(u,v) - f(x,y)| \leq 2 C \delta
$$
Because 
$$
  |e \cdot \nabla f|\leq \sum_i |e_i|C \leq 2 C
$$ Then it's possible to plug this knowledge in the error term above and get a uniform bound on the error in the question.

Comment: I don't see how the equality follows. Could you elaborate on the first integral?

Comment: I added some more steps, do you need even more explanations?

Comment: Yes, it is not clear to me how you reach $f(x,y)\delta_x \delta_y$, by having control over the estimate on $A$.